# Place minified files into jar

Tags: maven, minify

I will use the maven dependency **com.samaxes.maven#minify-maven-plugin** to minify my frontend project. This frontend- project is packaged into a jar (java archive) - so I have no war file because I use Spring boot.

With the configuration at the bottom *.min.js and *.min.css files are generated but they are not pacakged into jar file. I have read some threads and I have tried something but with no success: in the JAR file there are still the unminified css and js files.

Does anyone have any hint what I can do. I have a lot of css and js files in my project in different folder structures and the minified files should be placed in the same place like the unminified files are.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-minify</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <charset>UTF-8</charset>
          <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
          <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
          <closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
          <webappSourceDir>src/main/resources</webappSourceDir>
          <cssSourceDir>./</cssSourceDir>
          <cssTargetDir>./minified</cssTargetDir>
          <cssSourceIncludes>
            <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
          </cssSourceIncludes>
          <cssSourceExcludes>
            <cssSourceExclude>**/*.min.css</cssSourceExclude>
          </cssSourceExcludes>
          <jsSourceIncludes>
            <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
          </jsSourceIncludes>
          <jsSourceExcludes>
            <jsSourceExclude>**/*.min.js</jsSourceExclude>
          </jsSourceExcludes>
          <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>minify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**[EDIT]**

I have edit the Maven plugin in this way. 
I really have to use src/main/recoures - it a specification at our project.

My problem now is that the files in the different folders unter the under the main folder path **public/app** are minified BUT the folders with the minified files are at same level than my **public** folder is.

So I would need something like this:

```
<webappTargetDir>**public/app/**${project.build.outputDirectory}</webappTargetDir>
```

Is there a possibility to do it like this?

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-minify</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase><!-- When omitted defaults to 'process-resources' -->
        <configuration>
          <charset>UTF-8</charset>
          <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
          <closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
          <webappSourceDir>src/main/resources/public/app</webappSourceDir>
          <webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</webappTargetDir>
          <cssSourceDir>./</cssSourceDir>
          <cssSourceIncludes>
            <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
          </cssSourceIncludes>
          <jsSourceDir>./</jsSourceDir>
          <jsSourceIncludes>
            <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
          </jsSourceIncludes>
          <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>minify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

With the **minify-maven-plugin** configuration above I get the following folder structure at the left side but I would need the folder structure at the rigth side. Is there any possibility to do that?

[image: Current and needed folder structure]

Comment: First you should change the phase of minify plugin to `prepare-package` furthermore you should not use `src/main/resources` and change `webappTargetDir` to `${project.build.outputDirectory}`(target/classes folder)......If you use `src/main/resources` folder which is copied during the resources phase into `target/classes` which is not really what you want....

Comment: Thanks for the resonse. is there any possibility to place the minified files where the original file path is? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if you try `<webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/public/app</webappTargetDir>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats almost that what I want. The only problem I currently have is how to not package the not minified files - currently both are packaged. It would be great if there is another answer for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The files are copied relatively from `webappSourceDir` to `webappTargetDir`. So if you want the structure to match, you should use similar patterns for those. Meaning, it should be

```
<webappSourceDir>src/main/resources</webappSourceDir>
<webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</webappTargetDir>
```

or

```
<webappSourceDir>src/main/resources/public/app</webappSourceDir>
<webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/public/app</webappTargetDir>
```

I've commited the working example [here](https://github.com/Fantast/stackoverflow-test1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have one more question. How can I prevent packaging the not minified files intothe jar.

Comment: If they have the same name, they will be rewritten by minifier. If they have the different name, you will have to exclude them by the usual resource exclusion mechanism: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html.